# Different microcontrollers can communicate?

Tags: microcontroller, frequency

Can different microcontrollers communicate with each other? Are there any small chip that can communicate with 89C5131A-UM? And how do I know what frequency does the 89C5131A-UM communicate? I have read the datasheet but could not find it.

Comment: It communicates at whatever speed you've set the communications peripheral to.

Comment: This is kind of like asking if different humans can communicate with each other. And naturally, the answer will be just as broad as the question.

Answer (score 5):

Any microcontroller can communicate with another microcontroller in many different ways.

There are various standard communications protocols for which most micros have at least one or more dedicated peripherals built in such as UART, SPI, I2C, USB, CAN, etc.

For micro to micro the most common is usually SPI, I2C or UART, of which your micro has all three. You need to read up on each to become familiar with the pros and cons (speeds, number of pins taken, complexity, etc) but the datasheet will have all the necessary info, and there are hundreds of tutorials out there (and related questions on here) to help you.
Frequency wise, as mentioned, you can choose to set the speed to whatever is within spec for the peripheral.

Even if you don't have the hardware peripherals built in you can "[bit bang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_banging)" simple communications such as [UART](http://www.romanblack.com/bitbangserial.htm) or [SPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus#Example_of_bit-banging_the_SPI_master_protocol). So the short answer is yes, there is always a way.

Comment: Thank you very much! So if I want to make them communicate by  wireless and I have a set of antenna, what would be the good baud rate or frequency to set it?

Comment: If you want them to communicate by wireless, you will need some RF module to connect to each micro. Something such as a [BlueTooth HC-05](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Wireless-Bluetooth-RF-Transceiver-Module-serial-RS232-TTL-HC-05-for-arduino-HE-/360761952386?pt=UK_Computing_Other_Computing_Networking&hash=item53ff168882) module which uses SPP is commonly used, you can simply connect your UART peripheral to the module and all the BT stuff is "invisible". Also there are xBee's, Wi-Fi, and many other RF options to choose from. Have a look on Farnell, Digikey, eBay etc.

Comment: What do you mean by BT stuff?

Comment: @WeiXionG - Sorry, "BT" means Bluetooth.

Answer (score 2):

Your mcu features include

- TWI (Two Wire Interface) 400Kbit/s
- SPI Interface (Master/Slave Mode)
- Full-duplex Enhanced UART (EUART)

So basically it has SPI, I2C and serial communication ability. Almost any mcu you can find will support these three and can be used to communicate between (two or more) devices

The actual used speed depends on the clock source of the mcu and can can be set using the registers related to each peripheral, I'm sure the datasheet explains each one in the relevant section.